# Translation label for Choice field are not working in Sonata Admin Datagrid filter

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle, symfony-2.7

I'm using Sonata Admin Bundle with Sonata User Bundle in my Symfony 2.7 application. I have a Property Admin page. Here is its configuration in my services.yml:

```
// ...
mybundle.admin.property:
    class: MyBundle\Admin\PropertyAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Property, label: Properties }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - MyBundle\Entity\Property
        - 'MyBundle:PropertyAdmin'
```

I added two custom action buttons in the property admin list. I had to add two translation strings `action_rooms` and `action_stations` for those two buttons in `app/Resource/SonataAdminBundle/translations/SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff` which I copied from `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Sonata/AdminBundle/Resources/translations/SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff`. They are working fine.

The problem is that translation for `label_type_yes` and `label_type_no` in the datagrid filter is not working although they are defined in `SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff`. Here is the screen shot of the property list.

[image]

I created `app/Resources/translations/MyBundle.en.xliff` with the content of `SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff` and I added `setTranslationDomain` in `services.yml` for `mybundle.admin.property`, but no success.

```
    calls:
        - [setTranslationDomain, ['MyBundle']]
```

They are not also working in the user list `/admin/sonata/user/user/list` that is generated by Sonata User Bundle. I notice that it was not working before I created `app/Resource/SonataAdminBundle/translations/SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff`.

[image]

I have the translator enabled in config.yml and parameters.yml.

```
// config.yml
framework:
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }

// parameters.yml
parameters:
    // ..
    locale: en
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `/app/Resources/translations/messages.en.xliff` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="filter.label_enabled">
                <source>filter.label_enabled</source>
                <target>Enabled</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="label_type_yes">
                <source>label_type_yes</source>
                <target>Yes</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="label_type_no">
                <source>label_type_no</source>
                <target>No</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

It seems overriding `app/Resource/SonataAdminBundle/translations/SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff` [unlike  what is said in the symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations).

Comment: I was using this workaround for a while and it was great. Then I updated something (as yet not worked out what the cause was) and now I have "1" and "2" shown instead of Yes and No, and the filtering doesn't work. Does that ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: @jrg this is a solution for your problem, http://stackoverflow.com/a/37864256/5763965 I'm looking for a "global" solution instead copy all code on every admin class.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that is is bug in the latest Sonata because label_type_yes/label_type_no use "messages" domain instead of SonataAdminBundle/SonataCoreBundle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check what profiler says, in 2.7 you have ability to check missing translations. Just check what translation is missing and put it into app/Resources/translations/MyBundle.en.xliff