# Sonata Admin: Boolean selectbox for boolean properties

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have defined a boolean property in my Entity:

```
    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @Assert\Type(type="bool")
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_managed", type="boolean", nullable=true, options={"default": true})
     */
    protected $isManaged = true;
```

When I use it in the sonata admin bundle it just generates an select box with values "1" and "2" - I expected "true" or "false" selection.

```
$datagridMapper
      ->add('description')
      ->add('isManaged', 'doctrine_orm_boolean')
```

generates the code:

```
<select id="filter_isManaged_value" name="filter[isManaged][value]" class="form-control select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" title="Is Managed"><option value=""></option>            <option value="label_type_yes">1</option>            <option value="label_type_no">2</option></select>
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
            ->add('isManaged', null, array(
                'label' => 'Is Managed',
                    ), 'sonata_type_translatable_choice', array(
                'translation_domain' => "SonataAdminBundle",
                'choices' => array(
                    1 => 'label_type_yes', // or 'True'
                    2 => 'label_type_no' // or 'False'
                ))
            )
```

[Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-translatable-choice)

Comment: Works fine - Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking for a "global" solution instead copy all code on every admin class.